# jquery, hide content until loaded

Tags: jquery

I am currently using this script to fade page transitions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).bind("unload", function() {});
    $("body").css("display", "none");

    $("body").hide();

    $("body").fadeIn(2000);

    $('a.fade1, a.fade2, a.fade3, a.fade4').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(700, redirectPage);
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }

});​
```

this works like a charm when the content is alredy in cache, but when an image needs to load it will momentarily appear then be hidden and faded in

so what i need is a way to hide the content until it is fully loaded and only after that let it be faded in

hope someone can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: You could serve up page with `display: none` on the body? that way it's always hidden until the jquery kicks in.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use CSS to hide the element by default and then show it when you like to.

**CSS**

```
body {
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // When the page has loaded
  $("body").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded.

See the [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

You might also consider to replace your "fadeX" classes with a single class, something like "fade"

Comment: The problem with css is that it has to retrieve the styleshiit first. so you would have to use <style> or style="". Otherwise before the styleshiit is loaded, the page would be still display and might result in a buggery flicker.

Comment: Fast Forward to 2021, the syntax has been updated. In order to escape JS errors, use: $(window).on('load', function(){
//your code
});

Answer (score 14):

I actually wouldn't use CSS to start with and here's why. If for some reason JS fails to load on the page, it will also fail to actually show the content of your page as well. I'd keep everything in the script and write to the DOM, so if it fails, nothing happens.

```
<script>
document.write('<style>body { visibility: hidden; } </style>');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    delay();
});

function delay() {
    var secs = 1000;
    setTimeout('initFadeIn()', secs);
}

function initFadeIn() {
    jQuery("body").css("visibility","visible");
    jQuery("body").css("display","none");
    jQuery("body").fadeIn(1200);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 13):

Why not put all the initial css using... CSS?

```
<head>
<!-- some stuff of yours -->
<style>body{display:none}</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Then your js needs to only worry about calling `fadeIn()`. This way when browser renders `<body>` tag, it already knows to hide it, so it won't be shown at all until your `fadeIn()` gets called.

Comment: Sometimes jQuery makes people lose sight of basic common sense. +1 for bringing it back.

Comment: lol, is "common sense' really the correct term?  Generally, it's would refer to something that people *commonly* know...

Answer (score 4):

Since the year is 2021, I would like to prompt that this is how the code needs to be written now, in order to escape errors:

**css**

```
body {
  display: none;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  // When the page has loaded
  $("body").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS for each image: visibility: hidden;

jQuery.ready: visibility: visible; (or use a fade or whatever you like).
Why `visibility` instead of 'display'? `display` will make a lot of 'jumps' and 'glitches' on your page when items start loading.

Also, you can try using [jQuery's load method](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead of `ready`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any reason why I'd favor `visibility:hidden` over `display:none` in this particular use case?

Comment: Yeah, I just edited my answer... `visibility` saves the blank space where the element should appear, while `display` simply removes it. Though I guess it's the same if you're working with the `body` elements... But still, it's a good thing to know.

Comment: Just using the `load()` method will do it.