# Delay div visibility until font has finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

How can I determine if a font has finished loading?

I can use the ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095529/hiding-everything-until-the-page-has-finished-loading) to delay displaying the div in question, but how can i know when the font is available?

I wish to delay displaying a div until the font used has finished loading.

```
The current effect is that the words display in font A, then abruptly change into font B.
```

[jsFiddle demo (of the undesirable effect)](http://jsfiddle.net/1fvcf5zu/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if a font (@font-face) has already been loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312323/how-to-know-if-a-font-font-face-has-already-been-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

You could just wait for the whole page to load:

```js
$(window).bind("load", function() {
       $('.container').show();
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster:400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower:400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400);
div{font-family:'Segoe UI Light';font-size:3em;}

.container { /*container is hidden by default*/
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> <!--Wrap  everything in a container-->
  <div id="a1">This Is Line One</div>
  <div id="a2">this is line two</div>
  <div id="a3">THIS IS LINE THREE</div>
  <div id="a4">this is line four</div>
</div>
```