# Select Drop Down differs when use size attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used `size` attribute here to limit the list:

[image]

```html
<div class="select-editable"> 
  <select size="3"> 
    <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option> 
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option> 
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option> 
    <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option> 
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option> 
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option> 
  </select>
</div>
```

But i want drop down like this visible under the select element.

[image]

```html
<div class="select-editable"> 
  <select> 
    <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option> 
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option> 
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option> 
    <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option> 
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option> 
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option> 
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? (A [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) will be the best) Are you using some plugin or something?

Comment: i want select option editable so i used nextElementSibling ,and now i wanted limit the list options , so i used size attribute , the options starts from top of select element ,i want options under . please help me

Comment: <form:select style= "z-index:1" id="selectSubBox" class="form-control" path=""  onmousedown="if(this.options.length>4){this.size=4;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
         </form:select>
         <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="subCategory" />
         <form:errors path="subCategory" cssClass="text-danger" />

Comment: Can you post the output html (not the **spring** syntax..)?

Comment: I use spring only ,do you want full jsp code ?

Comment: I understand.. but you spring code compile to html. The browser doesn't "understand" spring right?

Comment: <div class="select-editable">
  <select size="3">
    <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
 <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
  </select>
</div>

Comment: <div class="select-editable">
  <select >
    <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
 <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
  </select>
</div>

Comment: in first code i used size attribute ,that is not i wanted , see the second code i didn't use size but i want the drop down like the second code with limited list in the dropdown, if they is any alternative to size , will be nice .

Comment: `with limited list` if you will create only 3 `option` in the select, it will only 3 options in the dropdown. I don't need to limit it.

Comment: for your understanding i gave you the sample code in html, but it dynamically fetch list from database , it will be 10 to 15 options in the dropdown so i want to limit the dropdown .

Comment: `limit` mean that you don't want that all of the 15 options will be shown?

Comment: Yes i don't want all

Comment: So don't generate them all. Only the first five.

Comment: sir please help , i need drop down like in pic 2 , with limited options

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsbin.com/notiyuq/edit?html,css,output

Comment: yes but i want scroll bar for remaining options , only 3 options visible remain options with scrollbar . i hope you understand now

Comment: Now I understood! You want to show by default only 3 options and the rest in the scolled area. Well, you can't do this with native `select` you can only do this with a plugin. Is that OK?

Comment: Ok no problem but i want dropdown like  in the  pic 2 with scrollbar, please help me sir

Comment: There is one option to do so ,it's size =3 but it behaves differently, why so ???

Comment: That's how the browsers work.

Comment: Please send the code with plugin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504832/how-to-get-single-element-from-multiple-element-with-same-id    ,please give me solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plugin such as [jquery-ui selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/). With a this plugin you can customize your combo with css including limit the height of the `option`s box.

Demo: (Keep attention to the height I defined in the css)

```js
$( "#speed" ).selectmenu();
```

```css
.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu {
  height: 74px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select name="speed" id="speed">
  <option>Slower</option>
  <option>Slow</option>
  <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
  <option>Fast</option>
  <option>Faster</option>
</select>
```

http://output.jsbin.com/biqaka

**Update**

Bootstrap demo: (In [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) you have `size` property)

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 3
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>option</option>
  <option>option</option>
  <option>option</option>
  <option>option</option>
  <option>option</option>
  <option>option</option>
  <option>option</option>
  <option>option</option>
  <option>option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this is want i wanted but i  have own  dropdown design  ,i dont want this line <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">   , how to make it work without this line .

Comment: what this line of code does here <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

Comment: @coolrock It's a reference of jquery-ui design. You can easily override the design. See my update.. (It's just an example how to change the design). Also, there are a lot of plugins you can use. Are you using bootstrap or something?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir but this want i wanted , we can do this in another way , we don't need jQuery here,(class="form-control" data-size="3") is enough , but i have problem in integrating to my project ,

Comment: Thanks a lot sir but this want i wanted , we can do this in another way , we don't need jQuery here,(class="form-control" data-size="3") is enough , but i have problem in integrating to my project ,

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: (http://jsbin.com/yumanimefa/edit?html,css,output)  ,here my sample project  , how to use selectpicker with this code but my design shouldn't change anything , please help me

Comment: Thanks a lot sir , it really help me .

Comment: I glad to hear. Please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer so it will help to other people (I can [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/303669) too :))

Comment: sir i question  elm.parentNode.nextElementSibling.value = elm.value;   ,why parentNode used here . why cant we use elm.nextElementSibling.value

Comment: Ex: parent A have b and c child ,so b is sibling of c , why parentNode.nextElementSibling is used here

Comment: Because the plugin wrap the `select` with `div` so the `nextElementSibling` returns nothing. The `input` is sibling of the parent.

Comment: sir again i small problem ,please see following video , why input appear separate ,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZrlUtok2hM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: It's happening because the plugin init after the document already displayed. The simple solution is to hide the hole document and display it when it finish to load. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095529/hiding-everything-until-the-page-has-finished-loading

Comment: yes you are right sir , another question ,i had named select element id="selectSubBox" before without plugin i attached options at run time like this $("#selectSubBox").html(options); , now how to attach to wrapped element .

Comment: Try to use ´selectpicker('refresh')´ to refresh the plugin. Read in the docs. https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/

Comment: yes , now it works , could you suggest me any book to learn scripting languages ,really i struggle in scripting .

Comment: hello , photo preview is not working in IE11 , here is the code works fine in chrome,firefox , http://jsbin.com/hofusomiko/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Actually, I don't know a book. All of my resources come from the internet and newsletters. About your second comment, please ask a new question and post the link here I will try to help. Also, please accept the answer so it will help to other people. Good luck..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807048/photo-preview-is-not-working-in-ie?noredirect=1#comment64983810_38807048  ,photo preview is not working in IE11 ,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504832/how-to-get-single-element-from-multiple-element-with-same-id  , please give me solution