# JS, Datatables: wait until HTML table fully loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatable

In my webapp I render a large (> 1000 rows) table using html, boostrap and jquery datatables...

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var table_tab = $('#tab').DataTable({ ... });
  });
</script>

<table id="tab" class="table responsive table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
  <?php foreach... ?>
</table>
```

All rows are loaded at the first time, no ajax is used, and all search / filter operations are provided on the client by datatables.

The table is responsive and is correctly formatted by datatables. However, it takes a while (few seconds) until page is loaded. And because datatables javascript is not triggered yet, table displays unformatted and inresponsive until its html is loaded.

**What I want**

Hide the table until html is fully loaded and display a loading image in the meantime.

Do this without [css display none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734021/jquery-hide-content-until-loaded), because i want the table to be shown in a browser without javascript support.

**What I tried**

I created two divs one that holds the table and second for the loading image...

```
<div id="details_tab">
  <script type="text/javascript">$("#details_tab").hide();</script>
  <table id="tab" class="table responsive table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
<div id="loading_tab" class="jsonly">
  <div class="text-center vspace-20 bmarg-20">
    <img src="./images/loader.gif" width="40px" /><br/>
    <big>Loading data...</big>
  </div>
</div>
```

After window is loaded I hide image and show div with table...

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#details_tab").show();
  $("#loading_tab").hide();
});
```

It works. Nevertheless, the datatable is damaged. It doesn't fit to a proper bootstrap column and is stretched over other elements. Moreover the table isn't responsive and doesn't react to window size change.

Can you help me?

Comment: You want to display it in a browser without JS but use jQuery?

Comment: @Tim Hallyburton: Simply - the unformatted plain table is better than none, if there is no support for JS ;)

Comment: I does not makes sense. You want to use a fallback if the browser have javascript turned off, but want JS to hide and show the table ...?

Comment: In my opinion "database" is damaged, because while it's created, it's hidden, so javascript can't calculate proper size. Try to set opacity of "#details_tab" to 0.01 instead of hide + set position: absolute and z-index to -1. When loading is complete just hide loading, and set opacity back to 1 (+ reset position and z-index).

Comment: Have you tried with the very common `table_tab.columns.adjust().draw()` fix to this issue?

Comment: @jacqbus Thats it! The problem was exactly where you said. I replaced hiding and showing with opacity/position/z-index and it works great. THANK YOU very much.

Comment: glad to hear that - and now i noticed i wrote database instead of datatable but now it doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in DataTable you can add "initComplete": function(){the code to show the table or else}

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function after every resize
for height
 $('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height', get_the_right_height);
for width
$('#your_table').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();