# When page is loading images are shown disproportionate

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with a few images, I've used css to set the size of those images and it's working good, but when the page is loading for some miliseconds the images are shown disproportionate, it looks ugly. I believe they are showing before the css is applied on their current sizes.. Is it possible to correct this?

When loading page(it last miliseconds but doesn't looks good):

[image]

And once the page loads and css is applied:
[image]

Comment: Add your stylesheet on head tag

Comment: @SarjanDesai Please could you add your comment as a response so I can select it? I was using styling tags within the view and once I moved to head tag it's working properly.

Comment: AlexGH, you need to use @ to notice another user. Example: @SarjanDesai !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML page render from top to bottom. Adding style on header will apply all available style to body elements.

Adding style at bottom of body will render HTML tags first and then load stylesheet and then render ui again to apply style

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your stylesheet gets loaded as early as possible by placing it in the header of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding stylesheets to `<head>` will fix your issue. They load too late.

Answer (score 0):

3 options:

1. Add style in the header
2. add a page loader
3. page loader + hide content until is loaded [jquery, hide content until loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734021/jquery-hide-content-until-loaded)